# Apriori create 3 set of word from 2 set

Tags: python, apriori

I'm doing implement on Apriori algorithm at the moment I am stuck to create 3 set of word

Suppose I have list of 2 words like this

```
FI2 = [('a','b'),('a','c'),('a','d'),('b','d'),('b','e'),('e','f')];
```

First approach I did with by distinct all element into 1 word and using itertools.combinations of 3 which is the compute expesive and not right approach since  the result should be subset from C2

It should be like this result

```
C3 = [('a','b','c'),('a','b','d'),('a','c','d'),('b','d','e')]
```

I am having a problem how to approach this problem. I would be appreciate how to give me some guideline how to do this one

Comment: ? should ('a','b','e'),('b','e',f') also be in C3?

Answer (score 0):

any chance C3 is missing some values? ('b','e','f'), ('a','b','e')

im sure it's not the best way but its a start:

```
from itertools import combinations 

FI2 = [('a','b'),('a','c'),('a','d'),('b','d'),('b','e'),('e','f')]

# check if two tuples have at least one var in common
check_intersection = (lambda c: len(set(c[0]).intersection(set(c[1]))) > 0)

# run on all FI2 pairs combinations
# if two tuples have at least one var in common, a merged tuple is added
# remove the duplicates tuples from the new list
C3 = list(set([tuple(sorted(set(c[0] + c[1])))for c in combinations(FI2,2) if check_intersection(c)]))



print(C3)
#=> [('b', 'd', 'e'), ('a', 'b', 'e'), ('b', 'e', 'f'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), ('a','c','d'), ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

Comment: @someone Did you find my answer helpful, or do you need more help?